# Is a piecewise smooth curve contained in a single chart?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry

If $M$ is a smooth manifold of dimension $\ge 2$, and $\gamma:[a,b]\to M$ is a piecewise $C^1$ curve, is the image of $\gamma$ contained in the domain of a single chart of $M$? It should be emphasized that the domain of $\gamma$ should be compact. In the case when $\gamma$ has no self-intersections, this is true by virtue of a tubular neighborhood theorem. In the case when self-intersections are allowed, I'm not sure what to do because the tube self-intersects.

Comment: If you are allowing your domain to be $S^1$, which I suppose is equivalent to having a self-intersection, the answer is no.  Consider the longitude or meridian of a torus. Neither will be completely contained in a single chart.

Comment: @N.Owad That's not true, the torus $\setminus\{\text{point}\}$ is covered by a chart (recall the polygonal construction). So take a point not on the curve, etc.

Comment: @0celouvskyopoulo7 If the wedge of two circles in $T^2$ could be covered by a single chart, then $T^2$ could be covered by two charts (the complement of the wedge of two circles is a disk). But this is false; the least number of simply connected open sets to cover $T^n$ is $n+1$ (look up Lusternik-Schnirelmann category). I don't see how what you said is true.

Comment: @0celouvskyopoulo7: N.Owad is right and you are wrong: Torus minus a point does not embed in the plane (two smooth curves in the plane cannot intersect transversally in a single point). Thus, curves on surfaces provide examples. However, starting in dimension 3 it should be possible to find a single chart. (Details will be messy though.)

Comment: @Moishe What do you mean, cannot intersect transversally in a single point? (I know what transversal means.)

Comment: @BalarkaSen I see where I went wrong, there are two gluing operations going on.

Comment: @0celouvskyopoulo7 Two transverse circles in R^2 cannot intersect in a single point, because total intersection number of two transverse circles in R^2 is always 0 (because circles are nullhomotopic in the plane).

Comment: @BalarkaSen Oh, of course.

Comment: @BalarkaSen $T^2$ can be covered by two charts because $S^1$ can be covered by two intervals $U$ and $V$, then $U\times S^1$ and $V\times S^1$ cover $T^2$. But those are just cylinders. You might be right about $T^2-\{p\}$.

Comment: @0celouvskyopoulo7 You should make it clear exactly what you mean by "charts" then. Charts to me are diffeomorphic to R^n, but I do know of that more general definition you are using. In any case, it's still false that you can cover wedge of two circles in T^2 by a chart by Moishe Cohen's argument.

Comment: @BalarkaSen For my purposes, I just need the curve to be contained in an open set diffeomorphic to an open subset of $\Bbb R^n$. I agree with the rest of the argument.

Answer (score 0):

Let $M$ be the two-dimensional torus.
It is well-known that the complete graph $K_5$ can be embedded into $M$.
Also, we can achieve that the image of $\gamma$ is this $K_5$.
If $U\subset \Bbb R^2$ and a chart $U\to M$ contains the image of $\gamma$, we obtain an embedding of $K_5$ into the plane, which is absurd.